# how to change a var from outside $.fn

Tags: javascript, jquery

How can I change the value of var = messages (by extend) in the following function:

My code:

```
(function($) { 
    $.fn.test= function(options) { 
        var settings = {
             value_1: "100"
        }
        // Extend the options so they work with the plugin
        if(options) {
            $.extend(settings, options);
        }

         var messages = {
               remote: "something in german"
          }

        return this.each(function() { 

            console.log("german message ",messages.remote);        
            this.addEventListener("submit", function(o){
                   console.log("submit");
                   console.log("shout be in english: ",messages.remote);
                  o.preventDefault()
            })       

        })

    }
}(jQuery));
```

I tried this without any success:

```
(function($) {
    $.extend($.fn.formCheck.messages, {
          remote: "Please change this."
    });
}(jQuery));
```

my jsfiddle: [here](http://jsfiddle.net/hAfF2/4/)

I have seen something similuar [here](https://github.com/jzaefferer/jquery-validation/blob/master/src/localization/messages_de.js).

Comment: If you have a look to the origin example (https://github.com/jzaefferer/jquery-validation/blob/master/src/localization/messages_de.js) they have the same scops like me. How do they get it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

## [**JSFIDDLE DEMO**](http://jsfiddle.net/FyB3g/)

The reason `$.fn.formCheck.messages` does not work is because its `undefined`. You have not attached `messages` to `formCheck`. You can do so simply like this :

```
    $.fn.formCheck.messages = {
            required: "Dieses Feld ist ein Pflichtfeld.",
            remote: "something in german",
            email: "Geben Sie bitte eine gültige E-Mail Adresse ein.",
    }
```

Also the code assigning `messages` is INSIDE the `$.fn.formCheck = function(options) {..`
 function. Which means `messages` does not exist until that function is called. To fix this move the declaration outside the function call, that way it will always exist.

---

You can optionally still store out a local `message` var if you like:

```
var messages = $.fn.formCheck.messages;
```

http://jsfiddle.net/JEd22/

Comment: If you have a look to the origin example (www.github.com/jzaefferer/jquery-validation/blob/master/src/…) they have the same scops like me. How do they get it?

Comment: sorry there is no change with your example.

Comment: Thx for your response. Here is the link again: https://github.com/jzaefferer/jquery-validation/blob/master/src/localization/messages_de.js
I would like to change the value of messages from germn to english.

Comment: thx again. It looks like i have a scooping problem. Any idea how they get it in the original value.plugin? They are working with  messages: { ....

Comment: I have no idea what you are referring to, what is `value.plugin`? What do you mean by `messages : {`. Also if you found this answer helpful, please mark it accepted. I will still be here to help ;)

Comment: Please have a look to https://github.com/jzaefferer/jquery-validation/blob/master/src/localization/messages_de.js and the additional sourcecode behind. There you will get more info. That the original valuate-code i'am reffering to.

Comment: What am I supposed to do with this information? Are you using this plugin? Are you writing a similar plugin?

Comment: I' am using this as base for another plugin.

Comment: Please post another question with your additional problems and link me in the comments.